# Method for MouseListeners and KeyListeners not working with .addMouseListener for Buttons on a Jpanel, Java

Tags: java, swing, methods, mouselistener

I have been having difficulty with making a method of Listeners to use repetitively in my code. Also, I am new to this, so I am very sorry for anything I leave out on this. Though, now here is my method for the Listeners:

```
public static void keysEvents(Optional<String> output)
{
    MouseListener mouseEvents = new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseClick (MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            Integer mouseModifiers = mouseEvent.getModifiers();
            if ((mouseModifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == 
            InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
            {
                if (output == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("click");
                }
                //more options...
            }
        }
        public void mouseRelease (MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {

        }
    };
    //More listeners...
}
```

EDITED VERSION:

```
public static MouseListener keysEvents(Optional<String> output)
{
    MouseListener mouseEvents = new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseClick (MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {
            Integer mouseModifiers = mouseEvent.getModifiers();
            if ((mouseModifiers & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == 
            InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)
            {
                if (output == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("click");
                }
                //more options...
            }
        }
        public void mouseRelease (MouseEvent mouseEvent)
        {

        }
    };
    //More listeners...
    return mouseEvents;
    //How would I have it return different listeners?
}
```

Here is the code for the program's window:

```
    JPanel MainP = new JPanel();
    MainP.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 100, 30));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    frame.setBackground(Color.blue);
    JPanel _B1_ = new JPanel();
    JPanel _B2_ = new JPanel();
    JPanel _B3_ = new JPanel();
    JPanel _B4_ = new JPanel();
    Button _Continue_ = new Button("Continue");
    Button _Load_Game_ = new Button("Load Game");
    Button _Settings_ = new Button("Settings");
    Button _Exit_ = new Button("Exit");
    _Continue_.addMouseListener(keysEvents(Optional.of(""))); //<edited here.
    _Continue_.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    _Load_Game_.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    _Settings_.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    _Exit_.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    MainP.setBackground(Color.gray);
    _B1_.setBackground(Color.gray);
    _B2_.setBackground(Color.gray);
    _B3_.setBackground(Color.gray);
    _B4_.setBackground(Color.gray);
    MainP.add(_B1_);
    MainP.add(_Continue_);
    MainP.add(_B2_);
    MainP.add(_Load_Game_);
    MainP.add(_B3_);
    MainP.add(_Settings_);
    MainP.add(_B4_);
    MainP.add(_Exit_);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(!frameBorder);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(_minX, _minY));
    frame.setSize(windowX, windowY);
    frame.add(MainP);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Finally, if I asked wrongly in any way, please tell me; so I can do better, later on, when asking questions. Hope it does not suck hours out of your life like it did me.

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you in a deep way, you should strongly consider creating a valid [mcve]. This is a a small (focus on the *small* part) but *complete* program that has only code necessary to demonstrate your problem and to compile and run, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification. For example there's no way we can see in the code posted where you truly add the listeners and to what you're adding them to.

Comment: sorry, before I copied my code I must of removed a part of it, I will Fix it...

Comment: Before you "fix" again, consider creating that MCVE. It's a separate small program -- it forces you to create code that focuses on the problem and the problem only, and it won't be time wasted, trust me.

Comment: And this: `_Continue_.addMouseListener(keysEvent());` makes no sense. How can that compile when your keysEvent method is a `void` method -- it returns nothing?

Comment: In fact, is that what you're asking about? Are you having problems with compilation?

Comment: *"..addMouseListener for Buttons.."* A thousand times no! Buttons should have an `ActionListener`. It will respond to both mouse clicks and keyboard input, and is simpler to implement.

Comment: _Continue_.addMouseListener(keysEvents(Optional.of(""))); will compile, thats what I had a hour ago, but it did not work. Also a hour ago I had the method return a mouseListener. I changed it later on because I could not succeed with it.

Comment: Never heard of the Action Listener, never showed up when I searched how to do this.

Comment: "Button" is an AWT component. Use `JButton` for Swing. Variable names should not start with an upper case character or have "_" at the start and end.

Comment: Thanks guys. You are quite the help to one learning java though code.

Comment: If you want my blunt assessment, you appear to be biting off more than you can chew -- trying to learn a complex and likely dead or dying corner of Java -- Swing GUI construction -- before you have a solid grasp on the basics. Do yourself a favor and first study, learn and gain a solid foundation in the basics before moving on to more complex stuff. This will save you (and us) a world of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ActionListener`. This is a method used with JButtons, and I've used it many times. JButtons are more popular and are easier to use than Buttons. JButtons are part of the swing component. Here is an example of the usage of `ActionListener`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Example"); //Create a JButton with the text "Example"
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Code to be executed upon press goes here
    }
});
```

I'd also like to add to @camickr's comment; Java variables should always start with a lower case letter, and never start with _. For example, `JButton continue = new JButton("Continue");` would be the proper way to declare and initialize a button. Any word after the beginning word in a varable name should be capitalized. For example, `JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue");` would be the proper naming.